# Spring Cloud Stream Elmhrust.RELEASE cannot change Serde

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am unable to change the Serde of a channel (or a binding) using the syntax specified in the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_configuration_options_3).

Assuming my channel is `pcin`, I understand that I should indicate *valueSerde* and *keySerde* using the follwing properties `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcin.producer.valueSerde` and `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcin.producer.keySerde`.

However, I am receiving an exception :

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: java.lang.Long). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
```

I am trying to adapt the example from Spring Tips, by Josh Long : https://github.com/spring-tips/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-streams

I just changed the class `PageViewEventProcessor` as follows:

```
@Component
        public static class PageViewEventProcessor {

                @StreamListener
                @SendTo(AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_COUNT_OUT)
                public KStream<String, Long> process(@Input(AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_VIEWS_IN) KStream<String, PageViewEvent> events) {
                        return events
                            .filter((key, value) -> value.getDuration() > 10)
                            .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value.getPage(), value.getDuration()))
                            .groupByKey()
                            .aggregate(()-> 0L, 
                                    (cle, val, valAgregee) -> valAgregee + val, 
                                    Materialized.as(AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_COUNT_MV))

                            .toStream();
                }
        }
```

Instead of counting the number of events (page visits), I calculate the sum of durations of each visit.

Here is an extract of *application.properties* (from Spring tips sample):

```
# page counts out
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcout.destination=pcs
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcout.producer.use-native-encoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcout.producer.key-serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcout.producer.value-serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$LongSerde
#
# page counts in
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcin.destination=pcs
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcin.consumer.use-native-decoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcin.group=pcs
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcin.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcin.consumer.header-mode=raw
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcin.consumer.key-serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcin.consumer.value-serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$LongSerde
```

Are there any other required changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `pcin` bound on the consumer (input)? If so, you should use the properties as

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcin.consumer.valueSerde 
and
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcin.consumer.keySerde`

Your incoming value type is `PageViewEvent`. However, you are setting the value `Serde` to be `LongSerde`.

You can remove this property altogether: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcin.consumer.use-native-decoding=true` and let the framework does the JSON conversion for you. That way, the incoming type is automatically converted as `PageViewEvent` without you explicitly provide a value Serde.

If you must provide a value Serde (in which case, the native-decoding property must be set to `true`), then you have to provide a proper JsonSerde as the value `Serde`.

**Update**:

With the following changes, I am able to run the application without any errors.

I changed your code like this.

```
@StreamListener
@SendTo(AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_COUNT_OUT)
public KStream<String, Long> process(@Input(AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_VIEWS_IN) KStream<String, PageViewEvent> events) {

                    return events
                            .filter((key, value) -> value.getDuration() > 10)
                            .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value.getPage(), value.getDuration()))
                            .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))
                            .aggregate(()-> 0L,
                                    (cle, val, valAgregee) -> valAgregee + val,
                                    Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(AnalyticsBinding.PAGE_COUNT_MV)
                                    .withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).withValueSerde(Serdes.Long())
                            )
                            .toStream();
                }
```

The inner Serdes on `groupByKey` and `aggregate` calls are necessary since they are different from the default key/value Serde combination.

I also changed your config and cleaned it up:

```
#
# defaults
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.commit.interval.mms=1000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
#
# page views out
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pvout.destination=pvs
#
# page views in
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pvin.destination=pvs
#
# page counts out
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcout.destination=pcs
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcout.producer.use-native-encoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcout.producer.key-serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcout.producer.value-serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$LongSerde
#
# page counts in
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcin.destination=pcs
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcin.consumer.use-native-decoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pcin.group=pcs
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcin.consumer.key-serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.pcin.consumer.value-serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$LongSerde
```

Comment: You can take a look at these samples as well for a reference: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples

Comment: I made a copy/paste mistake when posting the question, but I was actually using consumer and not producer. I edited the question to fix that. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: I did remove the serdes from the config but it still does not work. I forked spring boot project in github : https://github.com/hlaaribi/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-streams. Can you point out what I did wrong?

Comment: @HL'REB I updated the answer. I was able to run it after making a few changes. Please take a look.